# Get result of a query with join Grails with where clause in two classes

Tags: sql, grails, join, left-join

I have this two classes:

```
 def car{
        String horsePower
        String type
        String status
        static hasMany = [drivers:driver] 
 }


 def driver{
        String name
        String surname
        Integer number
        Date bornDate
        static belongs to = [car:Car] 
 }
```

My goal is to find all the drivers born the `'1984-07-01'`  who drives a car in status `'AVAILABLE'`

I did some research on the net to find how to do it but i didm' find something useful, can you help me?

Thanks anyway, bye!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

am not sure,but try this one..

```
def criteria = Driver.createCriteria()
List drivers  = criteria.list {
    eq("bornDate", "1984-07-01")
     car {
            eq("status", 'AVAILABLE' )
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

That should do it, but the date needs to be a Date, not a String, so something like:

```
def sdf=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")
def searchDate=sdf.parse("1984-07-01")//or whatever the date is - use this searchDate
```